# Unknown code showing in GDB step through

Tags: c++, gdb

I was running GDB and while stepping through some simple C++ code, it started displaying the code below. Does anybody have any clues as to what this code is?

```
_Unwind_SjLj_Register (fc=0x28feac)
    at ../../../../src/gcc-4.6.1/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-sjlj.c:126
126     ../../../../src/gcc-4.6.1/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-sjlj.c: No such file or directory.
        in ../../../../src/gcc-4.6.1/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-sjlj.c
(gdb) step
128     in ../../../../src/gcc-4.6.1/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-sjlj.c
(gdb) step
131     in ../../../../src/gcc-4.6.1/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-sjlj.c
(gdb) step
133     in ../../../../src/gcc-4.6.1/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-sjlj.c
```

Comment: Check the source-file path, it's for the GCC internal runtime library. You shouldn't just step into internal code like that, all library and internal function call you have to step over (unless, of course, you're a GCC developer and are debugging that code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libunwind/libunwind-30/src/Unwind-sjlj.c) (don't know if that's the exact version you're using, but should be close enough to get the idea):

```
//
// Called at start of each function that catches exceptions
//
EXPORT void _Unwind_SjLj_Register(struct _Unwind_FunctionContext* fc)
{
    fc->prev = __Unwind_SjLj_GetTopOfFunctionStack();
    __Unwind_SjLj_SetTopOfFunctionStack(fc);
}
```

Generally, there's quite a lot of stuff that happens in compiled C++ code under the hood. When you step through the code, you often encounter cryptically-named compiler-generated functions, library functions like the one you've come across, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`unwind` usually denotes exception handling code, so it looks like you've instruction-stepped into a `throw`.